# Show a checkbox for true value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, webmatrix

I have a WebGrid that shows value from my table and an edit button. when a user clicks this button a pop up form or dialog form comes out and its populated with values from the same table I mentioned earlier.

I have managed to format date values and now interested in formatting the boolean value (true/false ) from my table to be displayed in a checkbox. At the moment its displayed as a textbox with value true or false.

Below is part of my code:

```
 $('#dialog-form2-edit').dialog(
            { 
//dialog form code .. this is fine

 $.getJSON('/Methods/GetCertificate/' + $(this).attr('id'), function (data)
                {   var certificate = data;
                    $('#edit-paid').val(certificate.Paid);
                    $('#edit-mark').val(certificate.Mark);
                    var date = new Date(parseInt(certificate.MarkDate.substr(6)));
                    var year = date.getFullYear();
                    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                    var day = date.getDate();
                    $('#edit-markdate').val(year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
                    $('#edit-markdate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

Below is part of my html

```
<div id="dialog-form2-edit" title="Edit Certificate">
        <form id="edit-certificate-form" action="@Href("~/Methods/UpdateCertificate")">
            <div class="row">
                <span class="label"><label for="markdate">Mark Date :</label></span>
                <input type="text" name="markdate" id="edit-markdate" size="20"/>
            </div>
           <div class="row">
                <span class="label"><label for="mark">Mark :</label></span>
                <input type=text" name="mark" id="edit-mark" size="15"/>
            </div>
```

The value Mark and Paid are boolean. Now I intend to have the type changed to text and need help to format the boolean value to checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to display your boolean value in checkbox.

```
$.getJSON('/Methods/GetCertificate/' + $(this).attr('id'), function (data)
                {
var certificate = data;
if(certificate.Pass == true){
     $('#edit-pass').attr('checked', 'checked')} 
 else {$('#edit-pass').removeAttr('checked', 'checked')};
// your other json data
})
```

The removeAttr is necessary since I am using jquery-1.4.2.min.js. Tested and its working

Answer (score 2):

If you have a server-side bool value, you can use [conditional attributes](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/201/Cleaner-Conditional-HTML-Attributes-In-Razor-Web-Pages) in Web Pages 2 to manage checkboxes. You provide the bool to the `checked` attribute of the checkbox using Razor:

```
@{ var myBool = true; }

<input type="checkbox" name="mark" id="mark" checked="@myBool" />
```

If the bool is `true`, `checked="checked"` is rendered. If it is `false`, the checked attribute is not rendered at  all.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I understand your solution. My problem is how to capture the value to be assigned to myBool variable. E.g with the MarkDate you notice the parseInt formatted the date in my javascript. I am interested in something similar where the value got from my getJSON if true then my checkbox is checked.

Comment: If you provide a value for the `value` attribute in a checkbox, that is what gets passed to the server if the checkbox is checked. If you do not provide a value, a default value is passed which is `on`. So, using the example I posted, if `Request["mark"] == "on"`, you should set myBool to true as the box was ticked.

Comment: I think we are not understanding each other. I am concerned with the populating my dialog with values from getJSON. One of the value a boolean and just want it to show as a checkbox. I followed this tutorial http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/176/WebMatrix-and-jQuery-Forms-Part-2-Editing-Data. However in the tutorial the database does not have a boolen values. Mine does and have to be displayed in a checkbox.

Comment: A checkbox will display a tick if it has an attribute of checked="checked". You can set that using jQuery: `$('#mark').attr('checked', 'checked');`